# UIActivityViewController Mangled and Missing Icons iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, social-networking, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using a standard "share sheet" UIActivityViewController in my iPhone only app; however, something really weird happens when the app is loaded onto an iPad, and the view controller is opened.

The Message and Mail icons are cropped, and it is missing the icons for AirDrop, Twitter and Facebook.

Link to App in the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/faceflusher/id910606748

The ShareSheet was created with the Social Sharing PhoneGap plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

[image: Mangled ShareSheet]

Comment: Which iOS version are you using? I would suspect that Apple made changes to its SDK or runtime, which broke something in PhoneGap, which hasn't yet been rectified and is causing this. You might try checking out PhoneGap forums and seeing if others have encountered something similar.

Comment: @ReidBelton It is iOS 7.1.2. Do you think this has something to do with PhoneGap, or do you think it is an error in the upscaling of the app? (It looks fine on an iPhone)

Comment: Have you tested it with other versions and seen the same behavior? I would definitely tend to think it's something to do with PhoneGap, yes. Unfortunately I know almost nothing about PhoneGap itself...but you don't see weird behavior like this with the native SDK.

Comment: @ReidBelton The weird part is that if the app is optimized for iPad, it works fine and has no problems displaying. What makes this any different from a regular iPhone-only compiled app that has been scaled up to iPad dimensions?

Comment: It's different because your PhoneGap app is really a self-contained web app. It's a completely different animal from using the native SDK.

Comment: Same problem here, with iOS 8.2 on iPad Mini 1st gen. and iPad 2. Native app not PhoneGap.

Comment: anyone ever get a solution?